# C Language - Tried to make an array stack data structure to implement a undo/redo "prototype", why isn't it working? :(

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

Basically I made a create_app() function to allocate 2 nodes in the stack, each having a pointer to an array[max]; undo() pops the last element, and before returning it, it adds it into the REDO node's array. redo() does the opposite, pops the last element in it's array, putting it into Undo's array before returning it. What did I do wrong ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define EMPTY_TOS (-1)

typedef struct node *node_ptr;

struct node
{
    int arr_size;
    int tos;
    int *arr_stack;
    node_ptr next;

};

typedef node_ptr STACK;

STACK
create_app(int max)
{
    STACK UNDO = (STACK) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    STACK REDO = (STACK) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
    {
        UNDO->arr_stack == (int *) malloc(max * sizeof(int));
        REDO->arr_stack == (int *) malloc(max * sizeof(int));

        if(UNDO->arr_stack != NULL){printf("Out of space!");}
        else
        {
            UNDO->tos = EMPTY_TOS;
            REDO->tos = EMPTY_TOS;
            UNDO->arr_size = max;
            REDO->arr_size = max;
            UNDO->next = REDO;
            REDO->next = UNDO;
            return UNDO;
        }
        

    }
    
}

int
isEmpty(STACK S)
{
    return(S->tos==-1);
}

int
isFull(STACK S)
{
    return(S->tos>=S->arr_size-1);
}

void
push(int x, STACK S)
{
    if(isFull(S)){printf("Stack full!");}
    else
    {
        S->arr_stack[++S->tos] = x;
    }
    
}

int
undo(STACK S)
{
    if(isEmpty(S)){printf("Nothing to undo!");}
    else
    {
        S->next->arr_stack[++S->next->tos] = S->arr_stack[S->tos];
        printf("%d",S->arr_stack[S->tos--]);

    }
    
}

int
redo(STACK S)
{
    if(isEmpty(S->next)){printf("Nothing to redo!");}
    else
    {
        int temp = S->next->arr_stack[S->next->tos];
        push(S->next->arr_stack[S->next->tos], S);
        S->next->tos--;
        printf("%d",temp);
    }
    
}




int main()
{
    
    
    STACK app = create_app(5);
    push(1,app);
    push(2,app);
    push(3,app);
    
    undo(app);
    undo(app);
    redo(app);
    redo(app);

    /* Expected output: 3223 */

    return 0;
   
    
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some small errors were in your code, like these ones in `create_app()` which seem like typos.

```
UNDO->arr_stack == (int *) malloc(max * sizeof(int));
REDO->arr_stack == (int *) malloc(max * sizeof(int));
                 ^
                 |

if(UNDO->arr_stack != NULL){printf("Out of space!");}
                    ^
                    |
...
```

and some `int` returning functions did not return anything in the `else` part which gave some warnings.

Here is the modified code, which worked fine for me

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define EMPTY_TOS (-1)

typedef struct node* node_ptr;
struct node
{
    int arr_size;
    int tos;
    int *arr_stack;
    node_ptr next;

};
typedef node_ptr STACK;

STACK
create_app(int max)
{
    STACK UNDO = (STACK) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    STACK REDO = (STACK) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
    {
        UNDO->arr_stack = (int *) malloc(max * sizeof(int));
        REDO->arr_stack = (int *) malloc(max * sizeof(int));

        if(UNDO->arr_stack == NULL){printf("Out of space!");
            return NULL;}
        else
        {
            UNDO->tos = EMPTY_TOS;
            REDO->tos = EMPTY_TOS;
            UNDO->arr_size = max;
            REDO->arr_size = max;
            UNDO->next = REDO;
            REDO->next = UNDO;
            return UNDO;
        }
        
    }
    
}

int
isEmpty(STACK S)
{
    return (S->tos == -1);
}

int
isFull(STACK S)
{
    return (S->tos >= S->arr_size-1);
}

void
push(int x, STACK S)
{
    if(isFull(S)){printf("Stack full!");}
    else
    {
        S->arr_stack[++S->tos] = x;
    }
    
}

void
undo(STACK S)
{
    if(isEmpty(S)){printf("Nothing to undo!");}
    else
    {
        S->next->arr_stack[++S->next->tos] = S->arr_stack[S->tos];
        printf("%d",S->arr_stack[S->tos--]);
    }
    
}

void
redo(STACK S)
{
    if(isEmpty(S->next)){printf("Nothing to redo!");}
    else
    {
        int temp = S->next->arr_stack[S->next->tos];
        push(S->next->arr_stack[S->next->tos], S);
        S->next->tos--;
        printf("%d",temp);
    }
    
}




int main()
{
    
    
    STACK app = create_app(5);
    push(1,app);
    push(2,app);
    push(3,app);
    
    undo(app);
    undo(app);
    redo(app);
    redo(app);

    /* Expected output: 3223 */

    return 0;
   
    
        
}
```

Result:

```
3223
```

However, always take precaution in deallocating the memory `malloc`ed using `free()`.

Comment: Thank you! Totally forgot to deallocate memory.
@swag2198 If I free(app) will I deallocate both nodes UNDO and REDO?

Comment: No. You have to free each of the UNDO and REDO stacks individually. Also you have to free the arrays that you have allocated inside them. Basically every malloc would require a corresponding free.

Comment: ok so free(S) free(S->next) and setting each's arr's tos to -1 (or free(S->arr_stack) and free(S->next->arr_stack)) is enough ?

Comment: Yes. First free the `arr_stack` arrays and then `S->next` and `S`. Note that setting `tos` to -1 doesn't free the arrays.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Stylistic comments: there is no need to cast the result from malloc(). A void * doesn’t need a cast. And when you give malloc() a size, it is better to use T *p = malloc(size of *p); for a type T. That way the variable and type will always match. If you use a sizeof(T) you are in trouble if you change the type and forget to update the sizeof(). It doesn’t change the behavior one bit, but the former is a little cleaner and the latter is a little safer.

Comment: Also, you only check for malloc errors for undo and not redo. It is a crash later if the redo allocation fails and it is a memory leak if you get data for redo but not undo. Then you return an error but you have allocated memory in the redo stack.